# How to echo a command before executing it

Tags: bash

I want to echo a command before executing it.  This command replaces string 'PROJECT_NAME' with 'Hello world' in file.yaml.

```
PROJECT_NAME="Hello world"
CMD="replace.py 'PROJECT_NAME' '${PROJECT_NAME}' file.yaml"
echo "${CMD}"
${CMD}
```

What's the proper way to quote this string so the command will execute and the echo will show the command?

Notice that the value of variable ${PROJECT_NAME} contains spaces, and replace.py takes exactly 3 args.

I tried escaping all the quotes (\') and dollar signs (\$).  I tried swapping single quotes (') with double quotes (").

With some quoting, it would treat each word in "Hello world" as a separate arg, so replace.py would choke on "world" not being the filename it expects.

I have read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 but still can't figure it out.  I prefer not to duplicate the command or use set -x (because it prints set +x when using that to turn it off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper way to store a command line and execute it later can be done in 2 ways:

1. Use BASH arrays
2. Use BASH function

**1. Using BASH array:**

```
PROJECT_NAME="Hello world"
cmd=("replace.py" "PROJECT_NAME" "$PROJECT_NAME" "file.yaml")
printf "%q " "${cmd[@]}"; echo
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Now run it as:

```
bash ./script.sh
replace.py PROJECT_NAME Hello\ world file.yaml
```

Note escaping of space by `%q` of `printf`. You can run this command line from shell directly also to verify it again i.e.

```
replace.py PROJECT_NAME Hello\ world file.yaml
```

**2. Using a function:**

```
#!/bin/bash

PROJECT_NAME="Hello world"
cmd() {
   set -x
   replace.py "PROJECT_NAME" "$PROJECT_NAME" "file.yaml"
   set +x
}

cmd
```

Now run it as:

```
./script.sh
```

and you will get the similar output:

```
+ replace.py PROJECT_NAME 'Hello world' file.yaml
...
...
set +x
```

You can run this command line also:

```
replace.py PROJECT_NAME 'Hello world' file.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use an array instead of a plain string, and then use `printf`'s `%q` format to re-add quotes and/or escapes where needed:

```
PROJECT_NAME="Hello world"
CMD=(replace.py 'PROJECT_NAME' "${PROJECT_NAME}" file.yaml)
printf "%q " "${CMD[@]}"; printf "\n"
"${CMD[@]}"
```

Note that this may not use the same quoting/escaping method you used when you created the array; for example, I tried the above and it printed:

```
replace.py PROJECT_NAME Hello\ world file.yaml
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
replace.py 'PROJECT_NAME' "Hello world" file.yaml
```

...just a different way of writing the same command.

Comment: It looks like you're saying there's no simple way (other than set -x) to escape the command  that doesn't clutter and would be obvious to most readers.  In that case, I would go with set -x.  Thanks.